# C dynamically allocate struct array and its components

Tags: c, arrays, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

What is the correct approach to dynamically allocate a struct array and its components in C? I have managed to do something that works,but I am kind of sceptical if it is correct.
I have the following code:

This is my struct array that I need to dynamically allocate:

```
typedef struct
{
    char *wrong;
    char *right;
}Dictionary;
```

This is the function I call when I need to initialise my struct array:

```
Dictionary *init_Dictionary(int nr_elem)
{
    Dictionary *dict;
    dict = malloc(nr_elem*sizeof(Dictionary));
    for(int i=0; i<nr_elem; i++)
    {
        char wrong[101],right[101];
        scanf("%s%s",wrong,right);
        dict[i].wrong = malloc(strlen(wrong)*sizeof(char));
        dict[i].right = malloc(strlen(right)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(dict[i].wrong,wrong);
        strcpy(dict[i].right,right);
    }
    return dict;
}
```

Then in my main function, I have this:

```
    int nr_elem;
    scanf("%d",&nr_elem);
    Dictionary *dict;
    dict = init_Dictionary(nr_elem);
```

Also,when I finish work with the struct, how do I free the used memory ?

**EDIT** Thank you all for the quick and indepth answers!

Comment: `dict[i].wrong = malloc(strlen(wrong)*sizeof(char));` -> `dict[i].wrong = malloc(strlen(wrong) + 1);` (you need an extra char for the string terminator, and `sizeof(char)` is redundant).

Comment: Don't forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*, and that the *null-terminator* needs space as well, and is *not* counted by `strlen`.

Comment: And you need to match each `malloc` (or similar) with a `free`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so I have to loop through my struct array and call free on each component of the struct ?

Comment: Yes, and after the loop `free` the "array" of structures as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program design isn't good, you should separate UI from algorithms. Instead of this, you should first take the user input, then store it in 2 strings and pass the strings as parameters to `init_Dictionary`.

As for the allocation, it is almost correct. But you forgot to allocate space for the null terminator, it should be:

```
dict[i].wrong = malloc(strlen(wrong)+1);
dict[i].right = malloc(strlen(right)+1);
```

Multiplying with `sizeof(char)` isn't meaningful, since the definition of `sizeof(char)` is always `1` on all systems.

In a production-quality application, you must always check the result of each `malloc`, then handle errors.

You free memory the same way as you allocated it, but in the opposite order since you need `dict` itself to be valid until you have deallocated its members:

```
for(int i=0; i<nr_elem; i++)
{
  free(dict[i].wrong);
  free(dict[i].right);
}
free(dict);
```

As a rule of thumb, each call to `malloc` must be matched with a call to `free`.

Comment: I would set all the pointers to null after freeing ,to avoid reuse.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis While that is certainly good practice, how feasible it is depends on the context. If you have a function such as `void cleanup (Dictionary* d){ free(d); }` then setting the pointer to NULL does no good, as it isn't returned to the caller.

Comment: I get your point.However when you are working with other people it's always good to avoid someone in the future break your code.For example someone takes your code and adds another free().

Answer (score 3):

For each allocation you need to allocate one more location to allow for `\0` (NULL terminator) at the end of the string.

```
dict[i].wrong = malloc(strlen(wrong)*sizeof(char) +1 );
dict[i].right = malloc(strlen(right)*sizeof(char) +1);
```

To free, you first need to free all the pointers `right` and `wrong` in the array and then free the main `dict` array. Optionally, you can NULL the pointers after free.

```
Dictionary* freeDict(Dictionary *dict, int nr_elem)
{
    for (int i=0; i<nr_elem; i++)
    {
        free(dict->wrong);
        free(dict->right);
        dict->wrong = NULL;
        dict->right = NULL;
    }
    free (dict);
    dict = NULL;
    return dict;
}

//To call.
dict = free(dict, nr_elem);
```

Comment: `dict->wrong = NULL;` That's pretty pointless, yeah? You are about to deallocate it anyway.

Comment: No it's not.It's always a good practice to set a pointer to null after free() to avoid reuse.

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Dogmatically following good practice rules without applying common sense is harmful. By reading this code, you can see that it is pointless. Or do you expect some maintainer of the code to crazy things with `dict->wrong` between `free(dict->wrong);` and `free (dict);`? That won't happen, so all it achieved was to slow down the `freeDict` function.

Comment: I understand what you say and I respect this.I just have another opinion.dict's scope here is above this function. dict created somewhere else and it might be out there in the code.So , let's assume that someone in the future takes your (let's say) 5.000 lines code and adds another free for dict.

Answer (score 2):

There's a bug in your implementation: `strlen(s)` does not count the terminating 0-character, so, despite one test may work successfully, this is actually an UB. `strdup` can do work for you; if you don't have it standard library, simply add 1 when allocating memory for string copies. Or even better: count string length once, then use this value to both allocate enough bytes and copy contents with `memcpy`.

Otherwise your algorithm is quite useful (provided an array of string pairs is really what you need, with no additional structure like search index or anything).

To deallocate it, add a destructor that performs element-wise deallocation and then frees the whole array:

```
void destroy(Dictionary *dict, size_t nr_elem) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < nr_elem; ++i) {
        free(dict[i].wrong);
        free(dict[i].right);
    }
    free(dict);
}
```